# Trying to remove ambiguous call in constructor involving int and long

Tags: c#, constructor, implicit-conversion, ambiguity, ambiguous

"The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'fInt.fInt(int, bool)' and 'fInt.fInt(long, bool)'"

Here are my two constructors:

```
public fInt(int i, bool scale = true)
{
    if (scale) value = i * SCALE;
    else value = i;
}

public fInt(long i, bool scale = true)
{
    if (scale)
    {
        if(i > long.MaxValue / SCALE || i < long.MinValue / SCALE) 
            Debug.LogError("fInt Overflow on creation with scaling");

        value = i * SCALE;
    }
    else value = i;
}
```

Here's how I'm calling one with int using implicit conversion:

```
fInt i = 8;
```

I would like to be able to use both int and long so that I may avoid an extra check if it's not needed.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?  Would I simply have to do this:

```
fInt i = (int)8;
fInt i2 = (long)9;
```

I'd rather not have the extra typing if I can avoid it.  Here are my implicit conversions:

```
//implicit int to fInt
public static implicit operator fInt(int i)
{
    return new fInt(i);
}

//implicit long to fInt
public static implicit operator fInt(long i)
{
    return new fInt(i);
}
```

Comment: You have quoted the compiler error but unless I am overlooking it, you have not indicated which line of code the compiler is referring to.  Can you do that?

Comment: You didn't post any code that, at least in VS2013, would generate the error you describe. Please be more specific about what your exact question is.

Comment: @phoog The error is in the implicit conversion.  The line "return new fInt(i);"...it stems specifically from calling the constructor in the following manner: "new fInt(123);".  I'm using Mono with Unity3D...maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: @PeterDuniho It generates the error for me in Mono.  I'm using it with Unity3D

Comment: @GrantWinney The problem is that it can't determine whether to use the int or long when doing something like "new fInt(123);"

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the Mono compiler. You may be stuck, at least until someone gets around to fixing the bug.

Comment: @GrantWinney It appears to work fine in Visual Studio.  123 should be considered an int while 123L should be considered a long.

Comment: @PeterDuniho It runs in VS so I'm assuming it's some sort of bug.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug in the Unity3D editor...as the code runs fine in Visual Studio.  It only mixes up the signatures when the second parameter is optional.

Comment: The optional parameter is required to cause the bug to occur? I.e. there's no ambiguity error dealing with methods that don't have the default parameter value? Maybe you should try implementing the optional parameter the old-style way. I.e. declare more overloads: `fInt(int i)`, `fInt(int i, bool scale)`, `fInt(long i)`, `fInt(long i, bool scale)`. The two overloads without the `bool` parameter of course just call their corresponding overload, passing the default value.

Comment: It should be more of a Mono C# compiler issue, where it cannot process the numbers in Microsoft C# compiler's way. So saying it is a bug of Unity editor is not 100% correct.